# How to terminate a child process as part of terminating the thread that created it

Tags: ruby, multithreading, child-process

I have a Ruby application that spawns a thread on-demand which in turn does a system call to execute a native binary.

I want to abort this call before the native call completes.

I tried using all options the Thread documentation provided, like `kill`, `raise` and `terminate`, but nothing seems to help.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
class Myserver < Grape::API
@@thr = nil

  post "/start" do
    puts "Starting script"
    @@thr = Thread.new do
     op=`sh chumma_sh.sh`
     puts op
    end
    puts @@thr.status
  end

  put "/stop" do
    @@thr.terminate
    @@thr.raise
    Thread.kill(@@thr)
    puts @@thr.status
  end
end
```

The thread appears to enter a sleep state as an IO operation is in process, but how do I kill the thread so that all child processes it created are terminated and not attached to root.

Doing `ps-ef | grep` for the script returns the pid, and I could try `Process.kill pid` but wanted to know if there are better options.

I don't have the option at this moment of modifying how the script is executed as it is part of an inherited library.

Comment: Can you add `@@thr.join` just after your call to `Thread.kill(@@thr)` and see what happens? Alternatively, try replacing `Thread.kill(@@thr)` with `@@thr.exit`, if you haven't already tried that?

Comment: @ArtOfCode That didn't help.. Looks like my only option is to get the pid and kill the process.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ps` is the only approach I've found that works. If you also want to kill child threads, you could use something like this:

```
def child_pids_recursive(pid)
  # get children
  pipe = IO.popen("ps -ef | grep #{pid}")

  child_pids = pipe.readlines.map do |line|
    parts = line.split(/\s+/)
    parts[2] if parts[3] == pid.to_s && parts[2] != pipe.pid.to_s
  end.compact

  pipe.close

  # get grandchildren
  grandchild_pids = child_pids.map do |cpid|
    child_pids_recursive(cpid)
  end.flatten

  child_pids + grandchild_pids
end

def kill_all(pid)
  child_pids_recursive(pid).reverse.each do |p|
    begin
      Process.kill('TERM', p.to_i)
    rescue
      # ignore
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Oddly enough I use a similar variant to the above, but I actually think there may be another way, without depending on "ps". Since I am using linux 99% of the time this is not a big deal for me, but it would be awesome if ruby could have direct support as-is, without anyone depending on ps as such.